# Anchor link isn't working in Accordion list

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have created an accordion list for a webpage in which my company will be providing templates for our clients to download online. I have found that when I click on the download link, it doesn't go anywhere at all. Which is strange. I can click on it but nothing happens.

**Things I have tried:**
I tried instead changing 'Download Template' to a paragraph tag with an anchor tag wrapped around it. Same problem.

I found that whenever I place this link outside of the accordion div that the link seems to work fine so I think that it might be the javascript for the accordion that is affecting the link. You'll find the example under the first tab 'Bannerstands'.

links:

[The Webpage](http://www.freedomcreativesolutions.com/design-fcs-guide-resources/templates/)

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lxfmhqz/

```
        <div class="accordion">
        <dl>
              <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Bannerstands</a></dt>
              <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">

<table id="downloadTemplatesProductTable">
            <tr>
                <td class="template-cell-one">
                    FCS Executive Series Retractable Banner 3383
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://freedomcreativesolutions.com/img/FCS-Executive-Series-Retractable-Banner.pdf" target="_blank" class="templatesDownload">Download Template</a>
                    <a class="viewProduct" name="viewProduct" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-h.psd.zip">View Product</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="template-cell-one">
                    5.5" x 8.5" - Vertical Saddle Stitch
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v.ai.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIllustrator" alt="Illustrator Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v.psd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesPhotoshop" alt="Photoshop Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v.pdf.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesAcrobat" alt="Acrobat Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v.indd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIndd" alt="InDesign Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v.jpg.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesJpeg" alt="JPEG Icon" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="template-cell-one">
                    5.5" x 8.5" - Horizontal Perfect Binding
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-h-pb.ai.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIllustrator" alt="Illustrator Icon" /></a>    
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-h-pb.psd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesPhotoshop" alt="Photoshop Icon" /></a>   
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-h-pb.pdf.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesAcrobat" alt="Acrobat Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-h-pb.indd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIndd" alt="InDesign Icon" /></a>    
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-h-pb.jpg.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesJpeg" alt="JPEG Icon" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="template-cell-one">
                    5.5" x 8.5" - Vertical Perfect Binding
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v-pb.ai.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIllustrator" alt="Illustrator Icon" /></a>    
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v-pb.psd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesPhotoshop" alt="Photoshop Icon" /></a>   
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v-pb.pdf.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesAcrobat" alt="Acrobat Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v-pb.indd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIndd" alt="InDesign Icon" /></a>    
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v-pb.jpg.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesJpeg" alt="JPEG Icon" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="template-cell-one">
                    6" x 9" - Horizontal Saddle Stitch
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h.ai.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIllustrator" alt="Illustrator Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h.psd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesPhotoshop" alt="Photoshop Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h.pdf.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesAcrobat" alt="Acrobat Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h.indd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIndd" alt="InDesign Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h.jpg.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesJpeg" alt="JPEG Icon" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="template-cell-one">      
                    6" x 9" - Vertical Saddle Stitch
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-v.ai.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIllustrator" alt="Illustrator Icon" /></a>   
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-v.psd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesPhotoshop" alt="Photoshop Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-v.pdf.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesAcrobat" alt="Acrobat Icon" /></a>  
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-v.indd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIndd" alt="InDesign Icon" /></a>   
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-v.jpg.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesJpeg" alt="JPEG Icon" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="template-cell-one">
                    6" x 9" - Horizontal Perfect Binding
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h-pb.ai.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIllustrator" alt="Illustrator Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h-pb.psd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesPhotoshop" alt="Photoshop Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h-pb.pdf.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesAcrobat" alt="Acrobat Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h-pb.indd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIndd" alt="InDesign Icon" /></a>
                    <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h-pb.jpg.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesJpeg" alt="JPEG Icon" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

              </dd>

            </dl>
          <dl>
              <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Targeted Mailing Lists</a></dt>
              <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
                <p>Targeted mailing lists are based on some sort of qualification.  
Why pay to send your message to people who won't be interested in your product or service. <a href="http://www.freedomcreativesolutions.com/marketing-printing-winston-salem/targeted-mailing-lists/">Click here for list counts.</a> </p>

              </dd>

            </dl>
            <dl>
              <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Successful Marketing</a></dt>
              <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
                <p>As any successful marketer knows, the key to successful advertising is getting your message in front of; possible buyers. Mailing lists can be designed that target the person or organization most likely to purchase your product or service.  
</p>

              </dd>

            </dl>
            <dl>
              <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Find and Sell: Most Desirable</a></dt>
              <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
                <p>Using income, age, homeowner/renter status, location, interests and other descriptive factors, Freedom Mailing can help you find and sell to the people most likely to desire your product and service
</p>

              </dd>

            </dl>
            <dl>
              <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Consumer Database</a></dt>
              <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
                <p> <a href="http://www.freedomcreativesolutions.com/marketing-printing-winston-salem/targeted-mailing-lists/">Click here for list counts.</a> Sample list of selects on our consumer database: Age, Sex, Income, Location, Renter/Homeowner, Age of children, Pet Owner, etc...</p>

              </dd>

            </dl>
            <dl>
              <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Business Database</a></dt>
              <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
                <p> <a href="http://www.freedomcreativesolutions.com/marketing-printing-winston-salem/targeted-mailing-lists/">Click here for list counts.</a> Sample list of selects on our business database: Business type, size, gross receipts, number of employees, years in business, location(s), etc...</p>

              </dd>

            </dl>

          </div>
```

Comment: ** e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault(); **  is stopping this.

Comment: I'm getting `[Violation] 'mousedown' handler took 501ms` in my js console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a click handler on `.accordion` that disables the default action of your links in that element. Looks like that code is just trying to target the `.accordionTitle` link, so I updated your selector to target that element instead so that it won't interfere with nested links in that element.

Changed `var accordion = $('.accordion');` to `var accordion = $('.accordionTitle');`

```js
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

(function(window) {
  "use strict";
  // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

  function classReg(className) {
    return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
  }

  // classList support for class management
  // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
  var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

  if ("classList" in document.documentElement) {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return elem.classList.contains(c);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.add(c);
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.remove(c);
    };
  } else {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
        elem.className = elem.className + " " + c;
      }
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), " ");
    };
  }

  function toggleClass(elem, c) {
    var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
    fn(elem, c);
  }

  var classie = {
    // full names
    hasClass: hasClass,
    addClass: addClass,
    removeClass: removeClass,
    toggleClass: toggleClass,
    // short names
    has: hasClass,
    add: addClass,
    remove: removeClass,
    toggle: toggleClass
  };

  // transport
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(classie);
  } else {
    // browser global
    window.classie = classie;
  }
})(window);

//fake jQuery
var $ = function(selector) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
};

var accordion = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionTitle');

//add event listener to all anchor tags with accordion title class
for (var i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
  accordion[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
      var classes = e.target.className.split(" ");
      if (classes) {
        for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
          if (classes[x] == "accordionTitle") {
            var title = e.target;

            //next element sibling needs to be tested in IE8+ for any crashing problems
            var content = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;

            //use classie to then toggle the active class which will then open and close the accordion

            classie.toggle(title, "accordionTitleActive");
            //this is just here to allow a custom animation to treat the content
            if (classie.has(content, "accordionItemCollapsed")) {
              if (classie.has(content, "animateOut")) {
                classie.remove(content, "animateOut");
              }
              classie.add(content, "animateIn");
            } else {
              classie.remove(content, "animateIn");
              classie.add(content, "animateOut");
            }
            //remove or add the collapsed state
            classie.toggle(content, "accordionItemCollapsed");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion dl {
  border: 1px solid #999
}

.accordion dl:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff
}

.accordion dt>a {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out
}

.accordion dd {
  background-color: color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em
}

.accordion dd>p {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 2em
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 38px
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0
}

.accordionTitle {
  background-color: #00aeef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff
}

.accordionTitle:after {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: .5em;
  float: right;
  -webkit-transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .6s ease-in-out
}

.accordionTitle:hover {
  background-color: #477ba7
}

.accordionTitleActive {
  background-color: #477ba7
}

.accordionTitleActive:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  transform: rotate(-225deg)
}

.accordionItem {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden
}

@media all {
  .accordionItem {
    max-height: 50em;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 1s;
    transition: max-height 1s
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:48em) {
  .accordionItem {
    max-height: 18em;
    -webkit-transition: max-height .5s;
    -moz-transition: max-height .5s;
    transition: max-height .5s
  }
}

.accordionItemCollapsed {
  max-height: 0
}

.animateIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: accordionIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .65s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-name: normal;
  -moz-animation-duration: .65s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: accordionIn;
  animation-duration: .65s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0s
}

.animateOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: accordionOut;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .75s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-name: accordionOut;
  -moz-animation-duration: .75s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: accordionOut;
  animation-duration: .75s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0s
}

@-webkit-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8)
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8)
  }
}

@keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <dl>
    <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Bannerstands</a></dt>
    <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">

      <table id="downloadTemplatesProductTable">
        <tr>
          <td class="template-cell-one">
            FCS Executive Series Retractable Banner 3383
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="http://freedomcreativesolutions.com/img/FCS-Executive-Series-Retractable-Banner.pdf" target="_blank" class="templatesDownload">Download Template</a>
            <a class="viewProduct" name="viewProduct" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-h.psd.zip">View Product</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="template-cell-one">
            5.5" x 8.5" - Vertical Saddle Stitch
          </td>
          <td>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v.ai.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIllustrator" alt="Illustrator Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v.psd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesPhotoshop" alt="Photoshop Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v.pdf.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesAcrobat" alt="Acrobat Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v.indd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIndd" alt="InDesign Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v.jpg.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesJpeg" alt="JPEG Icon" /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="template-cell-one">
            5.5" x 8.5" - Horizontal Perfect Binding
          </td>
          <td>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-h-pb.ai.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIllustrator" alt="Illustrator Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-h-pb.psd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesPhotoshop" alt="Photoshop Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-h-pb.pdf.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesAcrobat" alt="Acrobat Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-h-pb.indd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIndd" alt="InDesign Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-h-pb.jpg.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesJpeg" alt="JPEG Icon" /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="template-cell-one">
            5.5" x 8.5" - Vertical Perfect Binding
          </td>
          <td>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v-pb.ai.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIllustrator" alt="Illustrator Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v-pb.psd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesPhotoshop" alt="Photoshop Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v-pb.pdf.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesAcrobat" alt="Acrobat Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v-pb.indd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIndd" alt="InDesign Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/catalog-5.5inx8.5in-v-pb.jpg.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesJpeg" alt="JPEG Icon" /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="template-cell-one">
            6" x 9" - Horizontal Saddle Stitch
          </td>
          <td>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h.ai.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIllustrator" alt="Illustrator Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h.psd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesPhotoshop" alt="Photoshop Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h.pdf.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesAcrobat" alt="Acrobat Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h.indd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIndd" alt="InDesign Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h.jpg.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesJpeg" alt="JPEG Icon" /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="template-cell-one">
            6" x 9" - Vertical Saddle Stitch
          </td>
          <td>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-v.ai.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIllustrator" alt="Illustrator Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-v.psd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesPhotoshop" alt="Photoshop Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-v.pdf.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesAcrobat" alt="Acrobat Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-v.indd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIndd" alt="InDesign Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-v.jpg.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesJpeg" alt="JPEG Icon" /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="template-cell-one">
            6" x 9" - Horizontal Perfect Binding
          </td>
          <td>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h-pb.ai.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIllustrator" alt="Illustrator Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h-pb.psd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesPhotoshop" alt="Photoshop Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h-pb.pdf.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesAcrobat" alt="Acrobat Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h-pb.indd.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesIndd" alt="InDesign Icon" /></a>
            <a name="downloadTemplates" rel="/templates/gotprint.com/booklet-6inx9in-h-pb.jpg.zip"><img name="downloadTemplatesJpeg" alt="JPEG Icon" /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </dd>

  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Targeted Mailing Lists</a></dt>
    <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
      <p>Targeted mailing lists are based on some sort of qualification. Why pay to send your message to people who won't be interested in your product or service. <a href="http://www.freedomcreativesolutions.com/marketing-printing-winston-salem/targeted-mailing-lists/">Click here for list counts.</a>        </p>

    </dd>

  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Successful Marketing</a></dt>
    <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
      <p>As any successful marketer knows, the key to successful advertising is getting your message in front of; possible buyers. Mailing lists can be designed that target the person or organization most likely to purchase your product or service.
      </p>

    </dd>

  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Find and Sell: Most Desirable</a></dt>
    <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
      <p>Using income, age, homeowner/renter status, location, interests and other descriptive factors, Freedom Mailing can help you find and sell to the people most likely to desire your product and service
      </p>

    </dd>

  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Consumer Database</a></dt>
    <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
      <p> <a href="http://www.freedomcreativesolutions.com/marketing-printing-winston-salem/targeted-mailing-lists/">Click here for list counts.</a> Sample list of selects on our consumer database: Age, Sex, Income, Location, Renter/Homeowner, Age of children,
        Pet Owner, etc...</p>

    </dd>

  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Business Database</a></dt>
    <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
      <p> <a href="http://www.freedomcreativesolutions.com/marketing-printing-winston-salem/targeted-mailing-lists/">Click here for list counts.</a> Sample list of selects on our business database: Business type, size, gross receipts, number of employees,
        years in business, location(s), etc...</p>

    </dd>

  </dl>

</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked. Thanks, appreciate your help a great deal!

Comment: @MandyReynolds ah your code's kind of confusing. I thought you were using jquery but you're faking it's syntax and your `querySelector` only selects a single element. Changed some of your logic to add an event listener to each of the `.accordionTitle` links and updated my answer.